# issue when i would to install ZendSearch for Zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-search-lucene

When i,would to install **ZendSearch** for **Zend framework 2**, using this line commande

```
php composer.phar require zendframework/zendsearch:0.1
```

i got this error message :

[image]

composer.json

```
 {
    "name": "zendframework/zendsearch",
    "description": "a general purpose text search engine written entirely in PHP 5",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "zf2",
        "lucene"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://packages.zendframework.com/",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "ZendSearch": "library/"
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://packages.zendframework.com/"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zend-stdlib": "2.*"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can check on packagist site

https://packagist.org/search/?q=zendsearch

there is no "zendsearch" package ready to use

so you must add it manualy to repositories composer.json section.

your local  composer.json:

```
...

"prefer-stable": true, 
"minimum-stability": "dev",

"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSearch"
    }
],

"require": {
    "zendframework/zendsearch": ">=0.1"
},

...
```

Comment: maybe you need also:     "prefer-stable": true,
    "minimum-stability": "dev",

Comment: Where i must put this code "prefer-stable": true, "minimum-stability": "dev",  ?

Comment: i guess the same issue !!

Comment: i add it to my answer;)

Comment: i use this line commande "php composer.phar require zendframework/zendsearch:0.1" but nothing is working

Comment: put proper composer.json file in your folder and run "php composer.phar update"

Comment: can'i just download ZendSearch package and put it into Zend Directory ?